# Pre-compiled Clang can't see the Visual Studio headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, clang, header-files

I'm new to Clang.

I've used [this article](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html#an-example-using-the-llvm-tool-chain) to get started with pre-compiled Clang 3.5.0 and Visual Studio 2012.

When i tried to compile the following code:

```
// hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

like this

```
C:\..> clang -c hello.c -emit-llvm -o hello.bc
```

i got an error:

```
hello.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How do i make pre-compiled Clang see the visual studio headers?

Comment: Add an include directory to the command line? I'm not that familiar with clang. Usually for building apps you use a script that sets the include paths for the library folders/headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gmlacrosse** was right. I need to add include directory to the command line.

`-I` command line switch solves the problem:

`C:\..> clang -c hello.c -emit-llvm -o hello.bc -I "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include"`